# What are these strange shapes in my Plot3D[]?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Plotting a function, I noticed some strange spots away from the main feature, the dark purple here:

[image: 1]

You can see that they don't actually have any curvature themselves:

[image: 2]

Strangely, you don't see them if you look from the bottom:

[image: 3]

What are they from? Something about lack of precision or overflow or divergence?

Comment: Could you share a code? :)

Comment: Are you plotting the result of an `NDSolve` operation? If that is the case, you are trying to perhaps probe a time step of your equation beyond the limits imposed by numerical stability/stiffness for the solver type being used. Conjecture, at best.

Comment: @Kuba I will tomorrow when I'm at work, but... it's very involved. It's created by a function that calls about 20 other functions in making it.

Comment: @drN No, but it is an NIntegrate[] that creates it. I suspect that might be similar?

Comment: @YungHummmma Yes, I would suspect so.

Comment: @YungHummmma could you share your NIntegrate code?

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you've got some inconsistency in your `VertexNormals`.  This can certainly happen with numerically generated functions though, as others have rightly pointed out, it's hard to say for sure without some more specific info.  Here's a simple way to force this sort of thing to happen.

```
(* A list of vertices to feed to Polygon *)
pts = Flatten[Table[
    {{x, y, 0}, {x + 1, y, 0}, {x + 1, y + 1, 0}, {x, y + 1, 0}},
    {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}],
   1];

(* Orient the vertex normals upward *)
normals = Table[{0, 0, 1}, 
   Evaluate[Sequence @@ Most[List /@ Dimensions[pts]]]];

(* Flip a few of them *)
normals[[25, 1, 3]] = -1;
normals[[25, 2, 3]] = -1;
normals[[25, 3, 3]] = -1;
normals[[26, 2, 3]] = -1;
normals[[26, 3, 3]] = -1;

(* Visualize *)
Graphics3D[Polygon[pts, VertexNormals -> normals],
 PlotRange -> {-2, 2}]
```

[image]